# Where shouid I put the access token using oauth2.0?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am currently working on Oauth2.0 and Spring Security, and I have a question and post it like this.

Normally, if you use Oauth2.0, you can get access token through Callback url, right? But if the requested client server and the auth server are separated, where should the callback uri be set?

I thought it was right to set it up on the client side and send it to the server, but I wasn't sure.